AWS CLI: Query for S3 buckets missing a policy
I need to determine which - if any - of my buckets do not have a specific policy attached to them.
Is this possible with the aws CLI?  Specifically, I'm trying to find any buckets with a deprecated TlsVersion.

You'll need to write a program that gets a list of S3 buckets and then loops through each of them, making another call to retrieve the policy. Easier to do with Python, but you could do it with AWS CLI if you have Shell Script skills.
